# Cannot process bibliography with a ris file

Tags: biblatex, biber

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}  
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa} 
\addbibresource{dyslexia.bib}
\addbibresource[datatype=ris]{dyslexia3.ris}
\begin{document}
{
\cite{causesdyslexia} \\ % from file dyslexia.bib
\cite{test1}             % from file dyslexia3.ris, downloaded .ris file and appended ID  - test1 
\printbibliography
}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at Biber/Input/file/ris.pm line 123, <GEN9> line 26.
INFO - This is Biber 0.9.9
INFO - Logfile is 'dyslexia.blg'
INFO - Reading 'dyslexia.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing bib section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'dyslexia.bib' for section 0
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'dyslexia.bib'
INFO - Looking for ris format file 'dyslexia3.ris' for section 0
INFO - Found RIS data source 'dyslexia3.ris'
```

Please add the 'ris' tag!

Contents of the .ris file; first line blank

```
TY  - JOUR
ID  - test1
AU  - Macfarlan, Todd S.
AU  - Gifford, Wesley D.
AU  - Driscoll, Shawn
AU  - Lettieri, Karen
AU  - Rowe, Helen M.
AU  - Bonanomi, Dario
AU  - Firth, Amy
AU  - Singer, Oded
AU  - Trono, Didier
AU  - Pfaff, Samuel L.
TI  - Embryonic stem cell potency fluctuates with endogenous retrovirus activity
JA  - Nature
PY  - 2012/06/13/online
VL  - advance online publication
SP  - 
EP  - 
PB  - Nature Publishing Group, a division of Macmillan Publishers Limited. All Rights Reserved.
SN  - 1476-4687
UR  - http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature11244
M3  - 10.1038/nature11244
N1  - 10.1038/nature11244
L3  - http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/vaop/ncurrent/abs/nature11244.html#supplementary-information
ER  -
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What is your question or point? That biblatex somehow "ought to" support entries in RIS format?

Comment: Well, `biber` does indeed support .ris files. Judging from the output of the program it does also find the file. The reported error seems unrelated. But to be sure we need to content of `dyslexia3.ris` to reproduce the example.

Comment: Please can you show (if not too large) the .ris file or otherwise I'll need to get it from you for testing.

Comment: You might also try the biber 1.0 pre-release (for which you'll need the biblatex 2.0 pre-release). I think I know what this particular error is and it should be fixed there.

Comment: @Mico Gets above error when trying to use a .ris file. Tried two different .bib files, worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the latest biblatex 2.0 and biber 1.0 pre-releases available from SourceForge. I believe that this specific error with RIS sources is fixed there.

Comment: Tried this, but to no avail. No error this time, but '.bbl' is generated only when I don't use the '.ris' file. Console output virtually the same, save for last line:
    INFO - This is Biber 1.0
    ...
    INFO - Found RIS data source 'dyslexia3.ris'
    INFO - Sorting 'entry' list 'apa' keys
    INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'English_United States.1252'

Comment: There were two issues. Firstly, your .ris file doesn't have a newline at the end of the "ER" field which makes it slightly illegal and tricky to parse. Secondly, there was a parsing error in the RIS driver. I have fixed this and uploaded a new 1.0 binary to SF. It works for me now. Note though that the output isn't perfect as your RIS source isn't great - the YEAR field is a bit of a mess, for example.

Comment: This works! Also tried `.ris` from different publishers, not all worked, maybe due to inconsistency in the fields or the way biblatex interprets them; but that's another issue. Prob solved, thanks!

Comment: Good. The problem with Ris is that everyone uses it slightly differntly and so it's often inconsistent in terms of the tag contents. The new biblatex 2.0 `\DeclareSourcemap` funtionality can help to regularise the data on the fly.

Comment: maybe you should add a `ris` tag.